# ASP.Net login status control not work with Intelligencia.UrlRewriter

Tags: url-rewriting

I use intelligencia.urlrewriter to rewriting my URLs.But I have a problem,when I use an asp.net log in status and trying to log off from site, LogoutPageUrl is changing to unclean URL.

for example when I'm trying to log off,My URL is **example.com/Mysite/en**
and the return URL must be http://example.com/login?returnurl=/Mysite/en

but the return URL is http://example.com/login?returnurl=default.aspx?page=Mysite&lang=en

I using **weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx** post back issues but this issue does not work with login status control...

please help me,I need to solve this problem.
thanks friends.